# Error when inserting through JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, gis, postgis, jdbc-postgres

When I run the sql statement below through `psql` it works fine, but when I try to run the same query by building it with a `preparedstatement`, it fails.

```
INSERT INTO Hvbp 
  (provider_number, weighted_clinical_process, 
   weighted_patience_experience, total_performance_score, 
   coordinates, latitude, longitude, address, city, state, zip) 
VALUES 
('010092', 43.909090909091, 13.5, 57.409090909091, 
 'POINT(33.206201 -87.525480)', 33.206200613000476, 
 -87.52548020899968, '809 UNIVERSITY BOULEVARD EAST', 'TUSCALOOSA', 'AL', '');
```

The error I keep getting is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "coordinates" is of type geography but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 203
```

The `coordinates` column is of type `GEOGRAPHY(POINT)`

Comment: Leave out the single quotes around `'POINT(33.206201 -87.525480)'`. That's a function call, not a string literal

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this doesn't actually work with the Postgres JDBC driver.  `statement.setString(1,"POINT(1 2)");` results in a complaint of `ERROR: column "geography" is of type geography but expression is of type character...`

Comment: Your SQL statement does not make use of parameters, that's why I wrote that. For a PreparedStatement you neeed `point(?,?)` in the SQL string (*without* single quotes) and *two* `setFloat()` calls to supply the values for each `?`

Comment: ireeder, it should be "POINT"(1,2), not "POINT(1 2)" as those are entirely different things.

Answer (score 3):

*I know this is an old problem, but I just spend most of the day debugging the same basic problem and finally found a fix*

What you're trying to do, is provide the `POINT` using WKT and have the server automatically convert that into a `Geometry`.

And as you've found that works if you include the WKT inside the body of the SQL, but fails if you use a parameter on a prepared statement.

There are 3 options for fixing it:

1. Use st_GeographyFromText in your SQL like so:

   ```
   INSERT INTO Hvbp(coordinates) VALUES( st_GeographyFromText(?) )
   ```

   And then set your parameters as WKT with `setString`.
   Depending on the frameworks involved, that might not be possible for you.
2. Use `setObject` on the preparedStatement instead of `setString`. For example:

   ```
   ps.setObject(1, "POINT(33.206201 -87.525480)", java.sql.Types.OTHER )
   ```
3. Change your JDBC driver settings to send strings as `unspecified` type, and then the server will do type conversions for you. To do that you want to change your JDBC URL to something like

   ```
   "jdbc:postgresql:my_db?stringtype=unspecified"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim - thank you for your help with a similar problem - I had to write ST_GeometryFromText into my database and the JDBC Driver threw a similar exception as @Hanks got.

For further reference and clarification for others - this is my result using Java with JDBC:

```
INSERT INTO streets.points ( point_id, the_geom ) 
        VALUES( ?, ST_GeomFromText( ? , 25832)  );
```

And the inserted Geometry-String looked like that:

```
POINT(33.206201 -87.525480)
```